# Conflict between Fontspec and xypic?

Tags: fontspec, xy-pic

I use the `xyling` package to draw tree diagrams. For the text I would like to use the CharisSIL font using the `fontspec` package. But combining these two gives poor quality tree diagrams: the lines are squiggly rather than straight. The trees are fine without fontspec.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\let\B\relax %to resolve a conflict in the definition of these commands between xyling and xunicode (the latter called by fontspec)
\let\T\relax
\usepackage{xyling} % for trees


\begin{document}

\Tree{&\K{CP} \V \\
\K{DP} && \K{C$'$} \V \\
& \K{C} && \K{IP}
}


\end{document}
```

[image: Example tree with CharisSIL]

[image: Example tree with standard font]

Comment: Have you considered using tikz instead. Lots of tree support.

Comment: There is no XeTeX driver in Xy-pic, as far as I know, so oblique lines are realized by joining small segments and they look jagged.

Comment: @egreg then why does the OP get a got result by removing `fontspec`?

Comment: @daleif Actually, with the OP's code I get *no* line.

Comment: Also `xyling` is from 2004, did XeLaTeX even exist back then. The first page of the manual explicitly mentions that `xy` is called with the `dvips` option

Comment: @egreg the problem of the disappearing lines is dealt with in the `xyling` documentation: The use of the dvips option might cause branches to disappear when you produce a pdf file with pdflatex. If you experience this, there are two ways of overcoming it:
1. erase the dvips option in the xypic call in line 57 of xyling.sty, i.e., use: \RequirePackage[color,all]{xy}. 
2. create the pdf file via dvips and ps2pdf conversion.

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd The problem remains with XeLaTeX, which is what the OP is using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `forest` package, but it's certainly not the only one out there.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\newfontfamily\charis{Charis SIL}

\forestset{
    mytree/.style={for tree={font=\charis}}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest} mytree,
[CP
    [DP]
    [C'
        [C]
        [IP]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```